# PHP script not executing properly shows blank page after processing

Tags: php, time, execution

i've been dealing with this annoying problem lately which consists of a php script that is supposed to execute quite heavy processing.

This script  has a loop that makes comparisons around 25000*25000

i have set maximum time out as 10800

but when i use $time = time(); in the begining of the script

and echo $time - time() at each iteration

script stops after 497 secs

Please help me figure out what could possibly be wrong with the script that i see a blank page after 497 seconds. 
Thanks.

EDIT:

```
   while($a<count($data))
   {
    $AL = (error_get_last());
    if($AL['type']==8)
            var_dump($AL);
    $i=0;
    $compdata[$a] = array();
    $row = explode("~",$data[$a]);
    $dl[$a] = 0;
    while($i<count($data))
    {
            $i += 1;
            if(($i-1)==$a)
                    continue;
            $rowc = explode("~",$data[$i-1]);
            $j=0;
            $cn = 0;
            $tw = 0;
            $kcv = "";
            while($j<$kc)
            {
                    if(Matcher($row[$kcn[$j][0]],$rowc[$kcn[$j][1]],$MCOUNT,$R))
                    {
                            $cn += 1;
                            $tw += $weight[$j];
                            $kcv .= $kcn[$j][2];
                    }
                    $j += 1;
            }
            if($tw != 0)
            {
             $compdata[$a][$i-1] = strval($i).$kcv;
             $dl[$a] += $tw;
            }
    }
    $compdata[$a] = join(",",$compdata[$a]);
    $a += 1;
      }
```

total loop run is about 25000*25000*10

Comment: It's hard to know the reason, but, can't you do this process in batch?

Comment: If you `echo ini_get('max_execution_time')`, does that output the expected 10800?

Comment: Yes it does but still theres some problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked in your [php.ini execution time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

Comment: It is set to 10800 only in php.ini